# Joining aggregate streaming dataframe with streaming dataframe in PySpark

Tags: python, join, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

Here is the code I'm trying to run

```
streaming_df = (
  spark.readStream
  .option("option1", "value1")
)

agg_df = (
  streaming_df
  .filter("filter1 = 'value1'")
  .select('col1', 'timestamp')
  .withWatermark("timestamp", "10 minutes")
  .groupBy(
    F.window('timestamp', "5 minutes"),
    'col1')
  .agg(F.first('timestamp', ignorenulls=True).alias('watermarked_timestamp'))
  .withColumnRenamed("col1", "watermarked_col1")
  )

watermarked_agg_df = agg_df.withWatermark("watermarked_timestamp", "10 minutes")

watermarked_streaming_df = (
  streaming_df
  .withColumnRenamed("streaming_col1", "watermarked_streaming_col1")
  .withColumnRenamed("timestamp_processed", "watermarked_streaming_timestamp")
  .withWatermark("watermarked_streaming_timestamp", "10 minutes")
)

join_df = (
  watermarked_streaming_df.join(watermarked_agg_df, how='inner', on=
    F.expr("""
           watermarked_streaming_col1 = watermarked_col1 AND
           watermarked_streaming_timestamp >= watermarked_timestamp AND 
           watermarked_streaming_timestamp <= watermarked_timestamp + interval 5 minute
          """))
)
```

I'm able to view data of watermarked_agg_df using watermarked_agg_df.display()

But there isn't any data showing up for join_df. I've made sure that there is some data in both the streams which satisfy the given conditions of the join.

Could anyone please let me know what am I missing here?

I've tried to change the watermark timestamp as well as window timestamp but it's futile.